# Laravel getting SoftDelete data by Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent, soft-delete

I have this Eloquent query:

```
$datos = Medidore::select([
    'medidores.*',
    'empresas.name as empresa',
    'tipo_medidor.descripcion as tipomedidor',
    'tipo1.descripcion as canal_1',
    'tipo2.descripcion as canal_2'])
    ->join('empresas', 'medidores.empresa_id', '=', 'empresas.id')
    ->join('tipo_medidor', 'medidores.cod_tipo_medidor', '=', 'tipo_medidor.id')
    ->join('tipo_canal_med as tipo1', 'medidores.canal1', '=', 'tipo1.id')
    ->join('tipo_canal_med as tipo2', 'medidores.canal2', '=', 'tipo2.id')
    ->whereNull('medidores.deleted_at')
    ->get();
```

It is not bringing any data, why? If I do this $datos = Medidore::all(); of course it works, with thrash data tho, because I need the joins.

How can I di that query with Eloquent, joins and SoftDeletes?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up your relationships: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships

In your Medidore class, it would be

```
public function empresa(){
  return $this->belongsTo(Empresa::class);
}
```

Ultimately your query will look something like this, assuming I understand your relationships right:

```
Medidore::with('empresa', 'tipoMedidor', 'canal1', 'canal2')->get();
```

Eloquent will automatically factor in soft deletes.  The returned collection of `Medidore` objects will already have loaded `$medidore->empresa` from the database

Comment: Nice, I'm still learning. I got now the message `Call to undefined relationship [empresa] on model [App\Models\Mantenedores\Medidores\Medidore`

Comment: You will have to put that relationship function into the Medidore class, as well as the other relationship functions like tipo

Comment: Hmm, that means that I'll have to change a lot of things, code and database. Laravel is expecting the id called`medidore_id`, jesus... I'm back to query builder.

Comment: @pmirnd you can use the additional parameters to define the columns, if needed.  Something like return `$this->belongsTo(Empresa::class, "empresa_id");` or `$this->belongsTo(TipoMedidor::class, "cod_tipo_medidor", "id");`